# Return floating windows to previous dock position in AvalonDock

Tags: wpf, avalondock

As i understand, in Avalondock when you drag a LayoutDocument a Floating Windows is automatically created, but if you dont dock it in a new place then stays floating and thats what im trying to avoid. Is there a way to force the floating window to return to its previous state/dock position rather than stays floating?

I'm using AvalonDock 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for the same, found a discussion on the AvalonDock site, saying that:

> You can float a LayoutContent calling its Float() method and re-dock it with Dock() or DockAsDocument().

Hope it still helps.

From discussion: [AvalonDock - View Discussion](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/359496)